# Chat using client.html on localhost and running server.js online?

Tags: node.js, localhost, socket.io

Can i create simple chat app where e.g. client.html is on my localhost server, and server.js is uploaded on nodester.com and running online (using socket.io)?

For example, how can I adapt the simple chat code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818029/node-js-socket-io-simple-chat) for working in the way described above (server.js on some server online and client.html on my localhost)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. Have a chat application running on AWS and the chat client running on localhost. Presume it should be possible with the others too.